# C3.js Line Graph Colors From URL

Tags: javascript, json, c3.js

So I am having troubles trying to change the colors of my line graph that is generated from JSON from a URL.  Here is my code to generate the chart:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
      url: '../URL.JSON',
      mimeType: 'json',
      keys: {
          x: 'Date',
          value: ["Line1", "Line2", "Line3", "Line4"]
      },
      type: 'line'
  },
  axis: {
      x: {
          type: 'category'
      }
  },
  size: {
      height: 500
  },
  colors: {
      'Line1': '#ff0000'
  }
});
```

And here is my JSON format:

```
[
    {'Date': '9/23/2014', 'Line1': 12, 'Line2': 54, 'Line3': 23, 'Line4': 5},
    {'Date': '9/22/2014', 'Line1': 56, 'Line2': 18, 'Line3': 25, 'Line4': 0}
]
```

For some reason the color does not change at all for Line1 with the colors attribute set.  So I was wondering if anyone knew how to change the colors to a url generated c3 graph.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my own question so I thought that I would post it here.

I had to add:

```
color: {
    pattern: ['#363FBC', '#363FBC', '#B73540', '#B73540']
}
```

Instead of:

```
colors: {
  'Line1': '#ff0000'
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. [The docs indicate the `colors` object](http://c3js.org/samples/api_data_color.html), but I also was not able to get it working without your example using the `pattern` array.

Answer (score 2):

The `colors` param should be inside the `data` object, like:

```
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 20, 50, 40, 60, 50],
        ['data2', 200, 130, 90, 240, 130, 220],
        ['data3', 300, 200, 160, 400, 250, 250]
    ],
    type: 'bar',
    colors: {
        data1: '#ff0000',
        data2: '#00ff00',
        data3: '#0000ff'
    }
}
```